# Make Nginx Ingress Controller work on AWS

Tags: amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

Currently following [this project](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ticketing/tree/master) that was deployed on DigitalOcean. I wanted to deploy it on AWS as learning experience.

Created EKS manually with basic settings, installed Helm and Nginx Ingress Controller on Cloudshell

```
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
kubectl create namespace ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
--namespace ingress-nginx \
--set controller.metrics.enabled=true \
--set-string controller.metrics.service.annotations."prometheus\.io/port"="10254" \
--set-string controller.metrics.service.annotations."prometheus\.io/scrape"="true"
```

Modified and deployed this ingress-svc.yml file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: my.domain.tld
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/payments/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: payments-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/tickets/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: tickets-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/orders/?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: orders-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
---
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.8.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

Added A record of EKS NLB to my domain in Route53, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Would also like to add the certs. But the steps is not clear to me.